# Identify the ethN interface containing a particular octet in CentOS

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ethernet, ifconfig

I have a specific need to identify which interface a part of an octet (e.g. `xx.xx.xx.112`) belongs to on a CentOS machine

My initial idea was to dump the output of `ifconfig` and parse it manually to identify the corresponding interface. Is it the right approach or a better way exists to do this?

My crude attempt would be something like below in `GNU grep`,

```
ifconfig | grep -B1 -E '\.112' | grep -oP 'e\w+:'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an `awk` answer might be slightly quicker since it won't need the extra subshells:

```
ip addr show | awk -F: '/^[0-9]/ {dev=$2} /inet .*\.112/ {print dev; exit}'
```

Another possibility, if you know an address that would be routed out the interface, like assuming there's a gateway at the `.1` address you could do

```
ip route get a.b.c.1 | cut -f3 -d' '
```

In general `ip` is the newer command that is supposed to replace `ifconfig`, though that's been true for a long time now and `ifconfig` isn't gone yet, but see [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig) about the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You might want to re-check the the input field separator, I guess it is un-terminated. Can you fix it please?

Comment: @Inian Oops, sorry for bad copy-paste, I fixed it to have the missing colon.  FWIW this is done on a centos 6 box, your output might be slightly different if you have a different version

Comment: Yup, it is working now. I was able to fix it myself, but my biggest concern apart from this would be, if this is the right approach (parsing output of `ifconfig`) to identify an interface for an IP? Would this be effective?

Comment: @Inian well, aside from the recommendation to switch to `ip` instead of `ifconfig` I don't think this is philosophically a bad approach, and I expect that it will indeed be effective.  Of course, depending on what you're trying to do in the end there may be other ways to accomplish that goal